# Is it possible to rotate a button group and fix it to the side of the window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

I'm looking to create a button group and align it to the left hand side of the screen. Something similar to this.

[image: Mockup of screen]

I've had some moderate success here - http://jsfiddle.net/5KQNP/  using

`-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);`

but I can't get it to sit correctly, The button group requires a manual width to be specified and it sits off screen rather then flush with the main container.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #sidebar {
     position:relative;
     height:20px;
     margin-left:20px; /* same as height of menu */
     left:-400px; /*same as menu width */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);     }

 #sidebar > sidebar-collapsed-nav {
     width:400px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to rotate it around the bottom left corner, that is:

```
.sidebar-collapsed-nav {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

And this property was creating problems: (remove it)

```
.sidebar-expanded {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KQNP/2/)